# Salesforce SSO using ADFS

Tags: single-sign-on

We have implemented Salesforce SSO for our Salesforce instance which is partially functional.

If we use the the SSO configuration in Salesforce which is enabled as a button at the bottom of the Salesforce standard login form within the company network we will be able to login straight into Salesforce, however this does not work if the user is not within the company network for example working from home which also applies to Salesforce1 app too.

Users trying to use the standard login form cannot login at all and they will get the password incorrect error.

Is there a way to still allow users to login to Salesforce from the standard login form when they put in their login credentials?

We have customised the domain etc too with no luck.

Any thoughts please?

Cheers,

Comment: We use SSO today and have no problems using the "button" on or off network and with personal devices.  Are your users prompted to enter their company credentials when they make a SSO attempt?  If not, it may be a ADFS setting on your company's end.